# Can a parameter be used to create a new object key and as a variable in the same function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, object

This is obviously a totally inefficient way to change the background color of a button, but I'm wondering why this doesn't work:

```
<button id="blueButton">Button</button>
```

```js
var data = {};

function changeColor(e){
  data.e = "blue";
  $('#' + e).css('background-color', data.e);
}

changeColor(blueButton);
```

If a variable is able to be used inside of a string (e.g. `${variable}`) why wouldn't it be able to be used in the above scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the key of an object by a variable you need to use bracket notation:
Keep in mind that javascript allows only `string` or `Symbol` as `Object` key. If you want to use some other type to key you need to have a look at [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```
var data = {};

function changeColor(e){
  data[e] = "blue";
  $('#' + e).css('background-color', data[e]);
}

changeColor(blueButton);
```

Comment: I can't believe I couldn't find that. Thank you. I'll mark it as correct as soon as it lets me.

Comment: @Hitmands thanks for adding information in the question, although I'd appreciate leaving a comment first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to store changed background color of each button id. below code should be helps to you. check console.log

```js
var data = {};

function changeColor(e){
  data[e] = "blue";
  $('#' + e).css('background-color', data[e]);
}

changeColor('btn1');
console.log(data);
changeColor('btn2');
console.log(data);
changeColor('btn3');
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">Button1</button>
<button id="btn2">Button2</button>
<button id="btn3">Button3</button>
```

In your code, seems you have passed id as object not a string. `data.e`, where `e` is property of data it is not passed parameters value.